# "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code" After installing kubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt, kubuntu, dpkg, kde

I can't install anything via terminal. This started when I installed KDE and failing (it shows a black screen on login) It won't let me remove KDE either. "apt-get -f install" won't work either.

Here's the terminal output after running "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell":

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 gnome-shell : Depende: gir1.2-clutter-1.0 (>= 1.22) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-mutter-3.0 (>= 3.18.1) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: libgjs0-libmozjs-24-0
               Depende: libgjs0e (>= 1.44.0) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: libmozjs-24-0v5 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (>= 3.18.2) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
               Depende: gir1.2-caribou-1.0 (>= 0.4.8) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-gcr-3 (>= 3.7.5) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 (>= 3.12.0) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-gweather-3.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 (>= 0.9.8) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-polkit-1.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 (>= 0.8.0) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 (>= 0.99) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gjs (>= 1.39.0) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gnome-session pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: gnome-backgrounds (>= 3.13.90) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: mutter (>= 3.18.1) pero no va a instalarse
               Recomienda: gnome-contacts pero no va a instalarse
               Recomienda: gnome-control-center pero no va a instalarse
               Recomienda: gdm3 (>= 3.10.0.1-3~) pero no va a instalarse
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depende: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) pero no va a instalarse
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

Translation (some things may be slightly wrong):

```
Reading package list... Done
Creating dependencies tree      
Reading status info... Done
You might want to run «apt-get -f install» to fix:
The next packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends on: gir1.2-clutter-1.0 (>= 1.22) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-mutter-3.0 (>= 3.18.1) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: libgjs0-libmozjs-24-0
               Depends on: libgjs0e (>= 1.44.0) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: libmozjs-24-0v5 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (>= 3.18.2) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
               Depends on: gir1.2-caribou-1.0 (>= 0.4.8) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-gcr-3 (>= 3.7.5) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 (>= 3.12.0) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-gweather-3.0 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 (>= 0.9.8) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-polkit-1.0 but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 (>= 0.8.0) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 (>= 0.99) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gjs (>= 1.39.0) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gnome-session but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: gnome-backgrounds (>= 3.13.90) but it's not going to be installed
               Depends on: mutter (>= 3.18.1) but it's not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-contacts but it's not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-control-center but it's not going to be installed
               Recommends: gdm3 (>= 3.10.0.1-3~) but it's not going to be installed
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it's not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try «apt-get -f install» without packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please could the OP or someone else translate this?

Comment: I'll translate once I get home.

Comment: @ubashu Added the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

for keeping your Packages up-to-date. Try

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
```

for deleting the package with all attached files and then use

```
sudo apt-get install -f gnome-shell
```

For installing all again.

Comment: I installed kubuntu, not gnome, should I run "sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop" instead?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my mistake